# Crash when instantiating ViewController from Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, storyboard

I have got a single view in my storyboard, which I add to my current view by doing the following :

```
MainViewController *mvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainController"];
             [self.view addSubview:mvc.view];
```

[image: storyboard]

The view appears, but everything I do after it appears, leads to a crash. What am I doing wrong ?

Here is an example when it crashes:

```
-(IBAction)showUsername:(id)sender{

    [testLabel setText:@"username"];

}
```

Everything is hooked up in storyboard as well, so falsely linked connections should not cause the problem.

Comment: you should show your crash log here...

Comment: there is nothing more than a blue "(gdb)" ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You instantiate a new view controller:

```
MainViewController *mvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainController"];
```

But you do not retain it. Your view hierarchy is, as soon you added it to another view.

```
[self.view addSubview:mvc.view];
```

So when a button is clicked, a message is sent to you `IBAction`, but your view controller has been released already. To prevent this from happening, retain your `mvc` variable, for example somewhere in a property.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) MainViewController *controller;

self.controller = mvc;
```

Comment: yes thank you, I asked this question again, and got the same answer... The problem has already been solved, but thank you anyway. I am sure this will help others too.

Comment: Love you <3 debug console doesn't even give a clue to find this out!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I can think all reason before you show log...

Comment: I think it gets released or not it is not properly instantiated... But I do not know how to solve it. I assigned it to my controller class, it should work fine.

Comment: @user1066899 you can press ctrl and drag your viewcontroller from ib to your .h file. then all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turn NSZombie on in the Product>>Edit Scheme you should get more descriptive Error showing then. Then you can add it.

Comment: Yeah thank you that works fine. Now I finally get the error, and as I assumed, my ViewController gets deallocated  `-[MainViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3fa5a60`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your method is declared and implemented correctly. Also make sure you have IBOutlet UILabel * testLabel in your .h. The only other problem I can think of other than that is how you hooked it up. Does it only crash when you press the button?

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong this will be why you are getting the error.

```
MainViewController *mvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainController"];
         [self.view addSubview:mvc.view];
```

replace it with this

```
 MainViewController *mvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainController"];
[self presentModalViewController:mvc animated:YES];
```

In storyboards you are not adding a subview you are doing one of three things presenting a modal, pushing it on to the navigation controller stack or making a custom one of these.

Comment: The addsubview is reserved for when the viewcontrolle has been presented.