# Get reference of a view in storyboard

Tags: ios

I have created a storyboard that contains a view controller with a view.  I'm writing separate   code files for the view and the view controller, so I need a way to get a reference to the view in the storyboard file.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using a .storyboard file? Slightly confusing as to what you've done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storyboard - refer to ViewController in AppDelegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186375/storyboard-refer-to-viewcontroller-in-appdelegate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your view controller in IB an identifier 
then get it like this

`MainViewController *mvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainController"];`

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150811/crash-when-instantiating-viewcontroller-from-storyboard)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to just get a reference to the view:

After creating your ViewController class (.h & .m) file, drag a ViewController into the Storyboard and type in this class name as this VC’s class.

You can then add a property in its .h file:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet YOURVIEW *view;
```

Access it like this:

```
[YOURVIEWCONTROLLERCLASS view]
```

---

_

Load the ViewController from the nib (Make sure, you’Ve set the identifier in the storyboard):

```
YOURVIEWCONTROLLERCLASS *vcref = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOURVIEWCONTROLLERCLASS”];
[[vcref view] doSomething];
```

---

_

Use your AppDelegate to refer to its VCs. You shouldn’t really consider this. There aren’t many cases were this is actually useful. Go with 1 or 2.